# Does the following sequence converge in product, uniform and box topologies?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the product, uniform and box topologies on $ \mathbb{R}^\omega$.

In which the topologies does the following sequence converge?

$$z_1 =(1,1,0,0, \ldots) $$

$$z_2 =\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0, \ldots\right)$$

$$z_3 =\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0, \ldots\right)$$

$$\vdots$$

My attempt:

By theorem 19.6 and example 2 page 117 in Munkres' topology book, in the box  topology, the sequence $z_n$ will not converge, but in the uniform and product topologies it will converge.

Is this correct?

Comment: This sequence converges in in the box topology. Assume $U=\prod_i\in\omega U_i$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0,...)$ with $U_i\ni 0$ open in $R$. Then for $N$ large enough $1/n\in U_1\cap U_2$. Therefore, $z_n\in U$. Should your example be $z_n=(1/n,1/n,1/n,...)$?

Comment: To the proposer: The 10 or 11 people in the world (like me) who don't have a copy of Munkres' book would like to ask what  Theorem19.6 and Example 2 Page 117 are.  We are curious as to what your  mistake was.:)

Comment: i lived  in Nepal  ,,very  backward  Area.and poor country .. there  is  no so much higher eduaction  system,,like iNDIA,USA  ,european counrty...as  my  english  language  is  also very weak,,,as  im newly learning topology..@DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converges in all three topologies to $(0,0,\ldots)$.

It is known that on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ we have

$$\text{ product topology } \subseteq \text{ uniform topology } \subseteq \text{ box topology}$$

Therefore, it suffices to show that the sequence converges in the box topology.

Let $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n$ be a basis neighbourhood of $(0,0,\ldots)$. Then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are neighbourhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so there exist $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge n_1 \implies \frac1n \in U_1$ and $n \ge n_2 \implies \frac1n \in U_2$.

Therefore, $n \ge \max\{n_1, n_2\} \implies \left(\frac1n, \frac1n, 0, 0,\ldots \right) \in \prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n$.

We conclude $\left(\frac1n, \frac1n, 0, 0,\ldots \right) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} (0,0,\ldots)$ in the box topology.

Comment: thanks   a  lots @ mechanodroid

Comment: You should also point out that if $(0,0,0,...)\ne x\in \Bbb R^{\omega}$ then in any of the topologies, $x$ has a nbhd that contains only finitely many terms of the series, so $(0,0,0,..)$ is the   $only$    limit point of the series.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Doesn't if follow from the fact that all three topologies are Hausdorff? So the only limit point must be precisely the limit $(0,0,\dots)$?

Comment: Yes. Obvious.  Now that you mentioned it.   I am sometimes obsessed with justifying every little detail. If you ask me to prove that $\pi>3.14$ I might start by defining $\Bbb R $.